# std::bad_alloc ulimit

Tags: c++, bad-alloc

I'm working on a 32bit Ubuntu 12.04. The RAM is 7.7 GB. When I run a certain process (written in C++) and reaches 50% of RAM usage, such process throws a "std::bad_alloc". 
The strange thing is that heap size is unlimited (command ulimit -v returns "unlimted"). 
So which can be the cause?

Answer (score 5):

On most 32-bit platforms, it's impossible for a process to address more than 4GB (2^32 bytes) of virtual memory. On 32-bit Linux, 1GB of the address space is reserved for the kernel, so user processes are limited to 3GB of addressable memory.

Answer (score 3):

On a 32-bit machine, even with [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension), a single process address space cannot be larger then 4GB.